# What are these evergreen berries/fruits?

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees, fruits, evergreens

We see these berries or fruits often in the Houston area, Texas. It looks evergreen, not sure if it's citrus.

[image]

Comment: ask the person who has them planted

Comment: Hi, denfromufa! This is a good picture for showing the size of the tree, but  can't see the fruit very well from this. Can you take close-up pictures of the fruits and leaves? It would also help if we knew approximately how big they are, too. (You could use those fence pickets, for size reference.) A picture of the bark wouldn't hurt, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a loquat ( *Eriobotrya japonica*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loquat).

It is a evergreen, and produce edible fruits.

Comment: Just ordered at Brighter Blooms Nursery!